# How to display color indexed image?

Tags: android, kotlin, imageview, android-imageview, indexed-image

Let say i have single channel image (2d matrix) with some `width` and `height` and with limited range integer values, lets say `0..14`.

I want to display this image/matrix on screen, but each value should be colored with custom predefined color (i.e color map/pallete).

What is the best/efficient way to do it in  Kotlin/Java?

Do i manually need to do the conversion from single channel to rgb bitmap? or maybe there is already a control that display the matrix as is with option to specify custom pallete? Is there any native that do it?

Comment: Interesting. I can't find anything about indexed image support in Kotlin docs.